# Javascript tree views that support multiple item drag/drop

Tags: javascript, ajax, treeview, drag-and-drop, extjs

We are currently using the ExtJS tree view in an application - a requirement has arisen requiring a user to select multiple nodes (which the tree view supports currently through a pluggable selection model) - but you can not then drag the multiple selections to another part of the tree.

Does anyone know of an ajax control (commercial or non-commercial) that supports multiple-selection drag / drop - or a example of enabling this functionality in ExtJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same issue.  I just found the solution :

```
..new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
  ...
  selModel : new Ext.tree.MultiSelectionModel()
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out this post in the ExtJS forum that details how you can enable multi-select in a Javascript tree.

http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=28115

Answer (score 0):

Ha i just asked the exact same question in their forum... want to acheive the goal without using the Custom User-Extension tough.

http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?97463-3.2.0-Treepanel-MultiSelectionModel-and-Dragdrop&p=459962

Just for reference.

Regards,
Fabian Loibl